# Node.js Error "version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by node)" after installing nvm

Tags: node.js, nvm

## Background

I moved from a direct installation of nodejs to installing nodejs via nvs (as recommended). I've removed nodejs and nvm and updated my system.

My system is a Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian (Debian v10 / Buster) installed.

## Preparation

Removed nodejs: `sudo apt-get purge nodejs`

Removed nvm and npm: `rm -rf $NVM_DIR ~/.npm ~/.bower`

Updated system: `sudo apt update` and  `sudo apt upgrade`

## Installation

I then installed nvm (as recommended) ...

`$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash`

... and - after opening a new command line window - the latest version (v21.6.2) of nodejs:
`nvm install node`

## Error

When I run nodejs, the following error always occurs:
`node -v`

`node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by node)`

I've been searching the internet for more than one hour without success. Any hint is highly appreciated.